# After updating to 20.10 from 20.04 I cannot connect to network

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet

After the upgrade to 20.10 everything seemed to go OK, until I tried to connect to my network. I have searched for a whole day on the internet for a solution but nothing found. I have checked that the Wi-Fi is working - the system grabs the DHCP address OK. Looking at the network configuration all seems to be in order, but I am unable to even ping 127.0.0.1! All worked perfectly in 20.04. I checked my router address and the gateway and cannot ping the router, even though it supplied my IP address.
Can anyone suggest where I need to look to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What I did to solve this:

1. disable ufw firewall (it has become active after upgrading)

   > sudo ufw disable
2. add DNS server to resolved.conf

edit /etc/systemd/resolved.conf and change or add this line:

```
DNS=8.8.8.8
```

Then change the /etc/resolv.conf symlink:

> sudo ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf